# Why one of my RDS MySQL instance supports up to 65536GiB of storage and the other one doesn't?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-rds, limit

**instance-1** (db.r5.4xlarge MySQL 5.7.26 - creation date: Wed Jul 08 2020 13:03:37)

The "Allocated storage" section of the Modify page says: `This instance supports multiple storage ranges between 100 and 65536 GiB.`

---

**instance-2** (db.r5.4xlarge MySQL 5.7.26 - creation date: Wed Jul 08 2020 12:32:03)

The "Allocated storage" section of the Modify page says: This instance supports multiple storage ranges between 14650 and 16384 GiB.

- This instance is reaching the 16384 GiB soon and I need to increase it.
- I recreated this instance from a snapshot of an old instance(where we are actually facing this issue) to see if that would fix the problem, but without success.

---

Can someone tell me why I cannot increase the instance-2 storage to higher than 16384 GiB?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible however this condition does exist `You can't make further storage modifications until six (6) hours after storage optimization has completed on the instance.`. Did you wait 6 hours before attempting to modify once you restored the instance?

16384 GB appears to be the maximum size for RDS running SQL Server only, all other RDS DB engines can go upto 65536 GB.

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html) on the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **innodb_file_per_table** then 16TB will be the maximum table size and DB storage size.

Search for **innodb_file_per_table** in the *Parameter Group* that the 16GB limited instance is using. If innodb_file_per_table is set to 1, this is the cause of the limit.

> For Amazon RDS MySQL DB instances, the maximum provisioned storage
> limit constrains the size of a table to a maximum size of 16 TB when
> using InnoDB file-per-table tablespaces. This limit also constrains
> the system tablespace to a maximum size of 16 TB. InnoDB
> file-per-table tablespaces (with tables each in their own tablespace)
> is set by default for Amazon RDS MySQL DB instances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.KnownIssuesAndLimitations.html#MySQL.Concepts.Limits.FileSize